# Align div tag inside table cell on re-sizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment, css-tables

I have a table that resizes, which works fine. The table header cells contain some additional `div` tags that represent how the table is sorted. For example, if a column is sorted, an ascending/descending image is shown. (Right now, I am using red boxes as placeholders.)

However, when I resize the table, the `div`s move *underneath* the text.

I tried this CSS:

```
overflow:hidden
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

It worked for the text of the table, but it did not help the `div`s. How can I keep the `div`s from moving underneath the text?

Here is my code: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8cN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make them absolute and add some padding to the cell to avoid superposition.

http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8cN/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the min-width property in the css.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a class like `ascending` or `descending` to indicate sorting respective to a column and apply **background-image** to these class and **background-position:right center** instead of using img tag

just proposing an option

Comment: I did not use any image. I am setting background-image to those div's using classes:sort1 and sort2.

Comment: then don't use those divs instead apply those classes to column header itself. may be this help

Comment: But I have two images to be set,how can two images be set as background? Is there any possibility?

Comment: use two diff classes `ascending` and `descending` respectively

Comment: But we can only put single image as background per a tag..ri8?

Comment: are you trying to apply both the classes `sort1` and `sort2` at the same time to same element?? as per your question we can have multiple images as background http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_multiple